# What is the most efficent way to filter an object with an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting, object

I'm trying to filter an Object by an array of arrays, getting back an array of objects.

Like this:

```js
 let obj =
{
  "a.1":1,
  "a.2":2,
  "b.1":3,
  "b.2":4,
  "c.1":5,
  "c.2":6
}

let array = 
[
  ["a.1","b.1"],
  ["a"],
  ["b","c.1"]
]

let expectedResult = 
[
  {
    "a.1":1,
    "b.1":3,
  },
  {
    "a.1":1,
    "a.2":2,
  },
  {
    "b.1":3,
    "b.2":4,
    "c.1":5
  },
]

// this is what I came up with
const filterObjectByArray = (obj, arr) =>
    Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(ch => {
        for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
            if (ch.startsWith(arr[index]))
                return true;
    })
    .reduce((ret, key) =>{
        ret[key] = obj[key]
        return ret
    },{})
    
let result = array.map(arr => filterObjectByArray(obj, arr))

//kind of deepEqual
console.log(JSON.stringify(expectedResult) == JSON.stringify(result))
```

Is there a easier or more convenient way to do that? I need to do this operation quite often and my object will be up to couple hundreds entries big, so I see a potential bottleneck here.

Comment: I would maybe take  a look to Lodash (http://lodash.com/) utilities

Comment: That's exactly how I would have done it. If you need to squeeze additional speed from it, I might test with unrolling the functional approach into purely procedural (i.e. without `filter` and `reduce`, just with vanilla `for`) and benchmark. However, I also suggest benchmarking *first*, to see whether this is as slow as you fear it is (if it's a couple of hundred entries, it should be reasonably fast unless you want it like million times per second). You know, "premature optimisation is the root of all evil" and all that.

Comment: Only beware `startsWith` - `a.15` starts with `a.1`, which I suspect might not be what you want. `(ch + ".").startsWith(arr[index] + ".")` is more reliable (`a.15.` starts with `a.`, but not with `a.1.`).

Comment: It might be more performant to create a tree e.g. a:{1:2,2:3},b: ... So you can filter more easily.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the tipp, i will look into it

Comment: @Jonasw what do you mean by tree, a nested object?

Comment: @jonas exactly. Depends on the real world usage if this is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a one type mapping of the "base" (the letter) to the "real" keys, and then use it to translate the letter to the real keys when create the object.

```js
const obj = {
  "a.1": 1,
  "a.2": 2,
  "b.1": 3,
  "b.2": 4,
  "c.1": 5,
  "c.2": 6
};

const array = [
  ["a.1", "b.1"],
  ["a"],
  ["b", "c.1"]
];

const getBaseKey = (key) => key.match(/^[a-z]+/)[0]; // get the base of the key - the letter. If it's only one letter, you can use key[0]

/** create a one time map of keys by their base **/
const oobjKeysMap = Object.keys(obj).reduce((map, key) => {
  const baseKey = getBaseKey(key);
  const curr = map.get(baseKey) || [];
  curr.push(key);
  return map.set(baseKey, curr);
}, new Map());

const result = array.map((sub) => // iterate the array
  [].concat(...sub.map((k) => k in obj ? k : oobjKeysMap.get(getBaseKey(k)))) // create the least of "real" keys
  .reduce((ret, key) => { // create the object
    ret[key] = obj[key];
    return ret;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```